# Enable RTT/TTY via profile on iOS 13?

Tags: ios, accessibility, configuration-profiles

My mobile provider (Vodafone Germany) does not seem to support RTT or TTY out of the box, thus the option to enable it is not visible on my iPhone.
Is there a way to enable the RTT/TTY option by installing a profile which overwrites my providers decision not to let me use RTT?

—Edit 1
So far I have found out that the availability of RTT /TDD lies within the .ipcc carrier bundle for the current provider, which in my case is ‘Vodafone.de 40.0’. There seems to be / have been a way to install custom carrier bundles, yet nowadays they must be signed so no more custom / self edited carrier bundles?

The quest now seems to be: how to edit the currently installed carrier bundle / how to install a custom carrier bundle under iOS 13.3.

Comment: According to https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/rtt-and-tty-iph3e2e47fe/ios this feature needs to be supported by the mobile provider and I didn't find anything related on vodafone.de, so I doubt that hacking the settings within the .ipcc will help.